# Push input fields from selected table row into array to loop through

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, foreach

I'd like to add some input fields from my table (specific row) to an array. Later I want to loop through this array.

I do it like this:

```
let selectedTr = [];
let arr = [];

$('td input:checked').each(function() {
    selectedTr.push($(this).closest('tr'));
});

selectedTr.forEach((tr) => {
  td = tr.find('td:not(:first-child) input');

  td.each(function() {
    arr.push($(this));
  });
});

// Doesn't work if I define arr like above (error: arr.each is not a function, if I use `arr = $('form input')` it works perfectly for example)
arr.each(function() {
    ...
});
```

Here is a short demo on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a4fpqynx/
PS: In jsfiddle I get: error object can not be cloned if I use `console.log()`.

arr shows something like (S on every line):

```
0 S [<input type="text">] (1)
1 S [<input type="text">] (1)
...
```

but I need (just one S)

```
S
0 [<input type="text">]
1 [<input type="text">]
...
```

so I can use `arr.each`.
PS: `arr.each(function() {})` is inside an other function which get called from multiple files to check input fields. I use this for login, tables and other forms.
How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const rowList = [...document.querySelectorAll('tr')]
  const inputList = rowList.filter(row => row.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.checked).map(row => {
      return [...row.querySelectorAll('input')]
  })
  console.log(inputList)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need the input fields inside the checked table row :). Not the checkboxes.

Comment: Gotcha will fix

Comment: @Lupin changed, let me know how that goes.

Comment: I'll try it :).